# Improving the speed of one-hot encoding a list of strings

Tags: python, performance, strings, numpy

I've recently developed two functions to functions to essentially convert a list of strings that look something like this (these strings are 101 characters long in my case):

`['AGT', 'AAT']`

To a numpy array:

```
array([[[[1],
         [0],
         [0],
         [0]],

        [[0],
         [1],
         [0],
         [0]],

        [[0],
         [0],
         [0],
         [1]]],

       [[[1],
         [0],
         [0],
         [0]],

        [[1],
         [0],
         [0],
         [0]],

        [[0],
         [0],
         [1],
         [0]]]])
```

The shape of which is `[2, 3, 4, 1]` in this case

At the moment, my code essentially defines one function, in which I define a dictionary, which is then mapped to a single input string, like so:

```
def sequence_one_hot_encoder(seq):
        
        import numpy as np

        mapping = {
        "A": [[1], [0], [0], [0]],
        "G": [[0], [1], [0], [0]],
        "C": [[0], [0], [1], [0]],
        "T": [[0], [0], [0], [1]],
        "X": [[0], [0], [0], [0]],
        "N": [[1], [1], [1], [1]]
        }

        encoded_seq = np.array([mapping[i] for i in str(seq)])
        return(encoded_seq)
```

Following from this, I then create another function to map this function to my list of strings:

```
def sequence_list_encoder(sequence_file):
    
    import numpy as np
    
    one_hot_encoded_array = np.asarray(list(map(sequence_one_hot_encoder, sequence_file)))
    print(one_hot_encoded_array.shape)
    return(one_hot_encoded_array)
```

At the moment, for a list containing 1,688,119 strings of 101 characters, it's taking around 7-8 minutes. I was curious if there was a better way of rewriting my two functions to reduce runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sequence_one_hot_encoder(seq)` builds an array of shape (len(seq), 4, 1). `sequence_list_encoder()` puts all these into a python list and then coverts the list into an array with shape (number_of_sequences, len(seq), 4, 1). It looks like there is a lot of overhead doing that. It is much faster to treat the `one_hot_encoded_array` as 1-D and then set the shape at the end.

```
def sequence_list_encoder(sequence_file):
    mapping = {
        "A": (1, 0, 0, 0),
        "G": (0, 1, 0, 0),
        "C": (0, 0, 1, 0),
        "T": (0, 0, 0, 1),
        "X": (0, 0, 0, 0),
        "N": (1, 1, 1, 1)
        }

    sequences = sequence_file.read().splitlines()
    bits = [b for seq in sequences for ch in seq for b in mapping[ch]]

    one_hot_encoded_array = np.fromiter(bits, dtype=np.uint8)
    one_hot_encoded_array.shape = (len(sequences), len(sequences[0]), 4, 1)

    return one_hot_encoded_array
```

This runs in about 1/5 the time as your code.